# adjust log time from

Tags: perl, awk

This log is recorded in Greenwich mean time, so I just subtract 5 hours from it every morning to get it to eastern time and and go through with my checks.

THis is the original data :

```
casper@casperbox:~$ tail /data/rafterman.log
115510.1 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01
115510.1 INFO successfully locked
115510.2 INFO starting
115510.2 INFO successfully set child death signal:
115510.2 INFO Env: 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin'
115510.2 INFO Env: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/
115510.2 INFO <- SYSSTATS
casper@casperbox:~$ tail /data/rafterman.log
```

I would lkie to figure out somththing like this:

```
06:55 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01
06:55 INFO successfully locked
etc.
```

How could I get a straight up 06:55 - what is an easy way to put a colon in between the hour and minutes? perl or awk one liner

```
casper@casperbox:~$ tail /data/rafterman.log | awk '{ $1 = $1 -50000; print } '
65510.1 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01  
65510.1 INFO successfully locked
65510.2 INFO starting
65510.2 INFO successfully set child death signal:
65510.2 INFO Env: 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin'
65510.2 INFO Env: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/
65510.2 INFO <- SYSSTATS
casper@casperbox:~$ tail /data/rafterman.log | awk '{ $1 = $1 -50000; print } '
```

Comment: What's your actual source data, and expected output?

Comment: What if the original time was 035510.2 - would you need to regress the date by a day when you subtract 5 hours?

Comment: I did not think of that Ed - that is why you probably make the big bucks - yeah, probably, Right now i am just checking the stuff that fires off at 6am. It is 24 hour time.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$ cat input
65510.1 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01  
65510.1 INFO successfully locked
65510.2 INFO starting
65510.2 INFO successfully set child death signal:
65510.2 INFO Env: 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin'
65510.2 INFO Env: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/
65510.2 INFO <- SYSSTATS

$ awk  '{sub("[0-9]{2}.[0-9]$", "", $1); sub("[0-9]{2}$", ":&",$1)}1' input
6:55 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01
6:55 INFO successfully locked
6:55 INFO starting
6:55 INFO successfully set child death signal:
6:55 INFO Env: 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin'
6:55 INFO Env: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/
6:55 INFO <- SYSSTATS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -pe's/^(\d{1,2})(\d{2})\d{2}/sprintf("%02d:%s", $1-5, $2)/e' log
06:55.1 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01
06:55.1 INFO successfully locked
06:55.2 INFO starting
06:55.2 INFO successfully set child death signal:
06:55.2 INFO Env: 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin'
06:55.2 INFO Env: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/
06:55.2 INFO <- SYSSTATS
```

(Accepts from STDIN too)

---

The following converts to local time. It even handles DST.

```
perl -MTime::Local=timegm -MPOSIX=strftime -pe'
   BEGIN { ($y,$m,$d)=(localtime)[6,5,4]; $y+=1900; $m+=1; }  # Guess

   ($y,$m,$d)=($1,$2,$3) if m{^\S+ INFO log opened for (\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)};

   s/^(\d{1,2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/
      strftime("%H:%M", localtime(timegm($3,$2,$1,$d,$m-1,$y-1900)))
   /e;
'
```

In Toronto, it outputs

```
06:55.1 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01
06:55.1 INFO successfully locked
06:55.2 INFO starting
06:55.2 INFO successfully set child death signal:
06:55.2 INFO Env: 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin'
06:55.2 INFO Env: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/
06:55.2 INFO <- SYSSTATS
```

In Vancouver, it outputs

```
03:55.1 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01
03:55.1 INFO successfully locked
03:55.2 INFO starting
03:55.2 INFO successfully set child death signal:
03:55.2 INFO Env: 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin'
03:55.2 INFO Env: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/
03:55.2 INFO <- SYSSTATS
```

---

If the `.num` is part of the timestamp (e.g. fractions of seconds), then all you need to do to remove it is to append `\.\d+` to the pattern. (This is the case for both of my solutions.)

Comment: I presume the `.1`, `.2` etc. are fractional seconds, so `115510.1` is `11:55:10.1`

Comment: I missed that. But don't you think the analysis belongs *before* the resolution?

Comment: Yes, better. But you misunderstand me. I think that that analysis (in this case, your assumptions and notes on variants) belongs before any resolution (here, your code). More generally, commentary on an insertion should precede the insertion. It follows spoken and literary practice. For instance it is best to say *"Oedipus is considered to have forfeited the throne"* before the play rather than afterwards

Comment: @Borodin, Footnotes belong in the footer. I don't think a minor detail should detract from the answer.

Comment: And there we differ. I think that your treatment of what I think is most likely a fractional second is a *major* detail, and that you should describe the behaviour of your Perl code *before* exposing it. I don't think there's much to be gained by arguing further; only the OP may know the semantics of the data that they have posted.

Comment: With the examples I have given I don't believe you misunderstand me. You could *move* the paragraph, yes; and I think your post would be better if you did. But in the end it is your post, and too many words have been spent talking about *your* words than about the problem at hand.

Comment: ikegami - pleae leave the post - I am processing they info. It is want I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you asked for:

```
$ awk '{$1=sprintf("%02d:%02d",substr($1,1,2)-5,substr($1,3,2))}1' file
06:55 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01
06:55 INFO successfully locked
06:55 INFO starting
06:55 INFO successfully set child death signal:
06:55 INFO Env: 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin'
06:55 INFO Env: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/
06:55 INFO <- SYSSTATS
```

but I'm not sure it's what you actually need, e.g. if subtracting 5 hours should take you back to the preceding day. If you do need to adjust the date after adjusting the time then what you need is this with GNU awk for gensub() and, more importantly, time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/log opened/ { oldDate = gensub("/"," ","g",$NF) }
{
    oldTime = gensub(/(..?)(..)(..)\..*/,"\\1 \\2 \\3","",$1)
    oldSecs = mktime(oldDate " " oldTime)
    newSecs = oldSecs - (5 * 60 * 60)
    newDate = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",newSecs)
    newTime = strftime("%H:%M",newSecs)
}
/log opened/ { $NF = newDate }
{ $1 = newTime; print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
06:55 INFO log opened for 2014/12/01
06:55 INFO successfully locked
06:55 INFO starting
06:55 INFO successfully set child death signal:
06:55 INFO Env: 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin'
06:55 INFO Env: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/
06:55 INFO <- SYSSTATS
```

You would see the difference between the 2 scripts if, for example, your timestamp was `035510.2` instead of `115510.2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is Mr.T from the A-TEAM. 
Instead of using one-liners like a fool - why not pipe your file into a perl script!!!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
    if ($_=~ /(^\d+\.\d+)Z/)    {
    my $new_time = $1 - 50000  ;
    my ($new_hour, $null) = split(/\./, $new_time);
    s/$1/$new_hour/g ;
    print $_ ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: wow  - . Mr. T. Didn't know you scripted, at the very least would think that you used python. I'll try it, Thanks T.